# readyapi virtual service : validate client sends second request 10s after sending first request

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I created 2 endpoints for a virtual service (/a and /b)

After client sends request to endpoint /a, I need to verify that after 10 seconds client sends a request to endpoint /b.

Is there a way to do this in readyapi?

I used the onRequest script in the virtual service to validate request body of request sent to /a but how do I verify that after 10 seconds request is sent to /b ?